# listview .clear() method

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I need to clear a listview (called "listImages").

I used the .clear() method, but this removed the headers too. When I then added items tot he list, they where invisible.

I decided that instead of using .clear() I would iterate through the list and .Remove them.

I do it like this:

```
    void clearList()
    {
        //.clear() seems to remove the headers, too. Weird :-/
        //listImages.Clear();
        listImages.BeginUpdate();
        for (int i = 0; i < listImages.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            listImages.Items.Remove(listImages.Items[i]);
        }
        listImages.EndUpdate();
    }
```

The list contains approx 400 items (each with three subitems) and when this code is called, it doesn't remove all the items from the list.

I call that function on a button press:

```
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearList();
    }
```

I have to click the button about 6/7 times before they are all removed.

At this point I am tempted to go back to using .clear() and then repopulating the headers again.

Is there a way to clear without removing the headers? Any idea why my loop isn't removing all the items from the list? It's a bit annoying.

Comment: `listImages.Items.Clear();`. If you want to use a loop, `RemoveAt(0)` or loop backwards.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you very much! That worked!